# How to convert unity's default materials to URP?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My project uses URP, but some of the library prefabs I want to use are using the unity's default material which is based on the Standard render pipeline. Is there a way to transition unity's default material to URP?

Note: I don't mind if unity's default material is converted to URP for all projects as I only use URP.

I tried selecting the default material to change it to URP, but it is not in the project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in editor window for this → [Render Pipeline Converter](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1/manual/features/rp-converter.html)

It will automatically remap built-in shaders according to the table in [Converting your shaders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1/manual/upgrading-your-shaders.html)